# Ошибка в синтаксисе команды при чтении из командной строки java

Tags: java, строки, командная-строка

Всем привет!
Недавно начал изучать язык Java. Пишу простенькую программу, в которой функция получает два параметра из командной строки. Первый аргумент - число, второй -  строка. Проблема в том, что когда я ввожу символ, например ">", вылезает "ошибка в синтаксисе команды". Получаемую строку я записываю в String. Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы из командной строки можно было читать любые символы?
Код:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
   double degree = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
   System.out.println(degree);
   String str = args[1];
   System.out.println(str);
   }
```

Comment: Приведите код - без него помочь почти невозможно. В данный момент не ясно даже не путаете ли вы ошибки компиляции и времени исполнения. Символ ваш вы в IDE вводите при редактировании кода или передаёте его в уже работающую программу? Если второе - то приведите логи ошибки. Ошибка в этом случае - не ошибка компиляции, но времени выполнения. Это очень разные вещи

Comment: Добавьте ещё, 1) точную команду, как вы запускаете свою программу и 2) точное (скопируйте и вставьте) сообщение об ошибке.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Символ `>` — особенный.

```
command > a
```

На языке командной строки (как bash, так и cmd.exe) это означает:

1. Выполнить программу `command`.
2. Всё, что она «печатает» (т.е. выводит в стандартный поток вывода, stdout) перенаправить
3. ... и писать в файл `a` вместо его прошлого содержимого. Если файла нет — создать новый.

Поэтому когда вы передаёте командной строке вот такое:

```
java helloworld >
```

Она это воспринимает так:

1. Выполнить `java helloworld`
2. И перенаправить вывод
3. Куда? А никуда. Ошибка в синтаксисе команды!

Поэтому делайте так:

```
java helloworld ">"
```

Comment: да, так работает. Благодарю.

Comment: @Piop хорошо, удачи )